# Where statements are not being appended

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am trying to build a query dynamically. It's initial state is fine. This is the initial where clause that should be present on every query

```php
$qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->andx(
    $qb->expr()->eq('s.competitor', $competitor),
    $qb->expr()->eq('s.ignored', $ignored),
    $qb->expr()->eq('s.id', $params['s_id']),
    $qb->expr()->eq('s.id', 'k.targetSite')
), true);
```

But the app I am building allows users to filter. When that happens, I want to add additional where clauses into my query builder. When this line is executed later in the code, it overwrites the above where statement.

```php
$qb->add('where',  $qb->expr()->like($col, $val), true );
```

From what I have read, the 3rd parameter `$append` should keep the previous statements, but that's not happening. In Doctrine 1.2, I could just do something like this:

```php
foreach($filter as $col => $val) {
    $dql->addWhere($col = ?, array($val));
}
```

How do I dynamically add where clauses to my QueryBuilder?

**Update**

Here is a full statement

```php
$where = array('col' => 'k.text', 'val' => 'some word%');

$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('s, sc')
    ->from('Dashboard\Entity\Section', 'sc')
    ->innerJoin('sc.keyword', 'k')
    ->innerJoin('sc.site', 's')
    ->leftJoin('k.keywordCategory', 'kc')
    ->leftJoin('k.keywordSubCategory', 'ksc');

$qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->andx(
    $qb->expr()->eq('s.competitor', $competitor),
    $qb->expr()->eq('s.ignored', $ignored),
    $qb->expr()->eq('s.id', $params['s_id']),
    $qb->expr()->eq('s.id', 'k.targetSite')
), true);

if ($where) {
    $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->andx(
             $qb->expr()->like($where['col'], $where['val'])
    ), true);
}

$qb->addGroupBy('k.id');
    $qb->addGroupBy('s.id');

$qb->setFirstResult( $params['start'] )
   ->setMaxResults( $params['limit'] );

$q = $qb->getQuery();
echo $q->getSql();
```

**And the output is**

```php
SELECT s0_.id AS id0, k1_.id AS id1, k1_.name AS name2, k2_.id AS id3, k2_.name AS   name4, k3_.id AS id5, k3_.text AS text6, k3_.search_vol AS search_vol7, s4_.id AS id8, s4_.sub_domain AS sub_domain9, MIN(s0_.rank) AS sclr10, MAX(s0_.created) AS sclr11 
FROM section s0_ 
INNER JOIN keyword k3_ ON s0_.k_id = k3_.id 
INNER JOIN site s4_ ON s0_.s_id = s4_.id 
LEFT JOIN keyword_category k1_ ON k3_.k_cat_id = k1_.id 
LEFT JOIN keyword_sub_category k2_ ON k3_.k_subcat_id = k2_.id 
WHERE k3_.text LIKE 'some word%' 
GROUP BY k3_.id, s4_.id LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

If I don't add in that `if ($where)` clause, then the first `andx` where statements are still in place. But when I try to dynamically add them, only the final WHERE statement is added, all others are cleared. I should also add, that I tried it like this as well.

```php
if ($where) {
    $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->like($where['col'], $where['val']), true);
}
```

I can successfully use

```php
$qb->andWhere( $qb->expr()->like($where['col'], $where['val']) );
```

But the API docs for Query Builder state the way I am trying to use it should be valid too. Wanted to make sure I was doing it right, or if it was a bug.

Comment: Can you paste the generated DQL statement here, with an example filter?

Comment: I added the full statement I am working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're able to use the ->andWhere() normally (and it will also fixes your issue).

Doctrine 2 QueryBuilder is a rather innovative concept (because it mixes both programmatic and fluent styles), and there are likely bugs associated to it.

One point that you should notice in your code: Instead of play with ->add('where', ...), you should think programmatic. Add more items to andX() object and at the end associate to the ->add('where', ...) (or even better: ->where(...))

Answer (score 3):

[Looking at the code](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php), it seems like what you're trying to do won't work, though whether that's documented anywhere or is just a bug is open to question, I think.

In `add()`, the DQL part you pass in seems only ever to be appended if the part is already stored as an array in the query builder:

```
   $isMultiple = is_array($this->_dqlParts[$dqlPartName]);
   ...

    if ($append && $isMultiple) {
        if (is_array($dqlPart)) {
            $key = key($dqlPart);

            $this->_dqlParts[$dqlPartName][$key][] = $dqlPart[$key];
        } else {
            $this->_dqlParts[$dqlPartName][] = $dqlPart;
        }
    } else {
        $this->_dqlParts[$dqlPartName] = ($isMultiple) ? array($dqlPart) : $dqlPart;
    }
```

And the WHERE clause, unlike most of the other DQL parts, is not initialised to an array:

```
private $_dqlParts = array(
    'select'  => array(),
    'from'    => array(),
    'join'    => array(),
    'set'     => array(),
    'where'   => null,
    'groupBy' => array(),
    'having'  => null,
    'orderBy' => array()
);
```

Now, this looks a bit like it's by design, but Doctrine 2 is fairly new and this bit seems to have been evolving recently. Personally, I'd raise a bug against this behaviour and see what the project people say. If nothing else, you might end up with improved documentation...